# Saving with a hash data and loading with it

Tags: php, html, hash

Now let's say that I am making a game. I would want to save data easily and rather lightly.

- How is it possible to games like Swarmsimulator, Cookie Clicker,.. games to save data with huge hashes like ASDasda29131ldfgksgj?
- And how can that data be read and returned with a valid game?

Basically what I want to know, in a rather simplified mode **How is it possible to save data to a  hash and load a game with that hash?**

Let's say my game would be saved to my local/session/cookie storage with hash = "owea2A2loa51ooa23", now where is that hash saved to?

Comment: They have a database table where the hash is the key and the game state is the value.

Comment: Place the user data in a single object, array, or similar. Convert that variable to a string using a serialize function. Save the string. When you load the string, use unserialize to turn it  back into the original variable.

Comment: Okay... Hmm.. How is it possible to my code to know what that game state has with it? I mean how does my code get the different values of different variables?

Comment: @KevinakaKebbona Based on my answer, you use unserialize on the hash to recreate the user variables. Based on Barmar's answer, you use a query to the database to fetch the user variables. Both methods are *very* simple.

Comment: @kainaw Could you give me a simple example of yours? And if you have time, his too?

Comment: @KevinakaKebbona This is NOT a "please write my program for me" website. Look at the PHP documentation. You will see unserialize in the manual. There will be MANY examples there. If you want to use PHP, you must learn to read the manual.

Comment: Kevin, it's worth deciding where you want to save your data first. If you store it using local or cookie storage, then it is stored on the computer, and can be wiped using browser options. Sessions on the other hand store the data on a remote server. Which do you need? Local/cookie storage is easy to achieve, but if users use multiple browsers/devices, their game data will fall out of sync.